# java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out exception while deploying app on Google App Engine

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I have made sample `Guestbook` application and i want to deploy that application on GAE but when i try to deploy it, it shows following exception :

```
    Unable to update:
java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$6.run(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$6.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getChainedException(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AbstractServerConnection.send1(AbstractServerConnection.java:285)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AbstractServerConnection.send(AbstractServerConnection.java:253)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AbstractServerConnection.post(AbstractServerConnection.java:232)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.ResourceLimits.remoteRequest(ResourceLimits.java:171)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.ResourceLimits.request(ResourceLimits.java:138)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AppAdminImpl.doUpdate(AppAdminImpl.java:440)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AppAdminImpl.update(AppAdminImpl.java:55)
    at com.google.appengine.eclipse.core.proxy.AppEngineBridgeImpl.deploy(AppEngineBridgeImpl.java:433)
    at com.google.appengine.eclipse.core.deploy.DeployProjectJob.runInWorkspace(DeployProjectJob.java:158)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.InternalWorkspaceJob.run(InternalWorkspaceJob.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:53)
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.readFully(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readDataRecord(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.AppInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTPHeader(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTP(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AbstractServerConnection.connect(AbstractServerConnection.java:133)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AbstractServerConnection.send1(AbstractServerConnection.java:283)
    ... 10 more
```

What could be the cause of it? Please help me solve this problem.
Thank you.

Comment: Give it a try after a while.

Comment: yes..it worked properly. I don't know how it worked automatically...i just restarted my eclipse and its done.

Comment: Could be a flaky network connection issue at time. Glad all is well.

Answer (score 3):

I've got such an error after Eclipse had been updated from 4.4 to 4.4.1. All plugins were lost, I reinstalled them, then the problem occurred.
I have tried:

1. Close-open Eclipse
2. Sign out - sign in into my proper Google account
3. Reinstall Google plugin
4. Wait for a few hours...

Nothing was helpful.
While my Eclipse 4.4.1 has an Internet connection.

The only working solution for me was to use [command-line tool appcfg](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/gettingstarted/uploading%20command-line%20appcfg)

Answer (score 1):

I solved the issue by signing out of google (bottom right in eclipse) and signing back again.

I hope it helps some one ...

This should be account which you use to publish to GAE

Answer (score 0):

I was just having that issue. If I leave a socket open on my laptop without it being plugged in the default power savings will kick in and the socket will be closed. If I leave it plugged in I do not have that issue.

Answer (score 0):

I also had this issue, and restarting Eclipse solved the problem.